How to apply downloaded patch Qt5webkit
~/buildroot-2024.08.2/package/qt5/qt5 webkit/
~/buildroot-2024.08.2/package/qt-webkit-kiosk/
how to apply this patch on these files
here is the patch
 diff --git a/package/qt5/qt5webkit/qt5webkit.mk b/package/qt5/qt5webkit/qt5webkit.mk
    index 6912359674..a850a03ca9 100644
    --- a/package/qt5/qt5webkit/qt5webkit.mk
    +++ b/package/qt5/qt5webkit/qt5webkit.mk
    @@ -50,6 +50,23 @@  ifeq ($(BR2_TOOLCHAIN_USES_MUSL),y)
     QT5WEBKIT_CONF_OPTS += -DENABLE_SAMPLING_PROFILER=OFF
     endif
    
    +define QT5WEBKIT_CONF_PRI
    +       $(SED) 's/QT.webkit.includes =.*/QT.webkit.includes = \$$\$$QT_MODULE_INCLUDE_BASE \$$\$$QT_MODULE_INCLUDE_BASE\/QtWebKit/g' -e 's/QT.webkit.libs =.*/QT.webkit.libs = \$$\$$QT_MODULE_LI>
    +
    +       $(SED) 's/QT.webkit_private.includes =.*/QT.webkit_private.includes = \$$\$$QT_MODULE_INCLUDE_BASE\/QtWebKit\/5.212.0 \$$\$$QT_MODULE_INCLUDE_BASE\/QtWebKit\/5.212.0\/QtWebKit/g' -e 's/>
    +
    +       $(SED) 's/QT.webkitwidgets.includes =.*/QT.webkitwidgets.includes = \$$\$$QT_MODULE_INCLUDE_BASE \$$\$$QT_MODULE_INCLUDE_BASE\/QtWebKitWidgets/g' -e 's/QT.webkitwidgets.libs =.*/QT.webk>
    +
    +       $(SED) 's/QT.webkitwidgets_private.includes =.*/QT.webkitwidgets_private.includes = \$$\$$QT_MODULE_INCLUDE_BASE\/QtWebKitWidgets\/5.212.0 \$$\$$QT_MODULE_INCLUDE_BASE\/QtWebKitWidgets\>
    +endef
    +QT5WEBKIT_POST_CONFIGURE_HOOKS += QT5WEBKIT_CONF_PRI
    +
    +define QT5WEBKIT_CREATE_SYMLINK
    +       ln -sf $(HOST_DIR)/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/mkspecs/modules/*.pri $(HOST_DIR)/mkspecs/modules/
    +       ln -sf $(HOST_DIR)/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include/QtWebKit* $(HOST_DIR)/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include/qt5/
    +endef
    +QT5WEBKIT_POST_INSTALL_STAGING_HOOKS += QT5WEBKIT_CREATE_SYMLINK
    +
     QT5WEBKIT_CONF_OPTS += \
            -DENABLE_TOOLS=OFF \
            -DPORT=Qt \

thanks in advance

Just apply it. From your buildroot directory:
patch -p1 < path/to/the/patch

If you have errors, the patch you have is for a different version of Buildroot and you'll have to apply the changes by hand.
